# How one can store user's settings in Calibre's plugin?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plugins, calibre

I am developing a Calibre's plugin and I want to store user settings (e.g. if the plugin should make a post-import conversion from one format to another - in my 
case: `pdf` to `djvu`).

How can I store user settings? Does Calibre have a build-in method to do this?

For example I have a dictionary `prefs_org_dict` with keys and values representing preferences set by an user. How can I store this data reliably and read it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method suggested by the [manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/creating_plugins.html#id8) is to create the `JSONConfig` object and store user preferences in it.

Basically just:

```
import os
from calibre.utils.config import JSONConfig

prefs = JSONConfig(os.path('plugins', 'PLUGINNAME'))
# JSONConfig inherits after Dict so use it as dictionary

for key, val in prefs_org_dict.iteritems():
    prefs[key] = val
prefs.commit() # explanation in 3rd section of this post
```

But this method has some caveats:

1. **Name of the settings file.** Paraphrasing manual:

   > Remember that this name (i.e. `'plugins/PLUGINNAME'`) is also in a global namespace, so make it as unique as possible. You should always prefix your config file name with `plugins/`, so as to ensure you don't accidentally clobber a calibre config file.

   After you save anything to this object you can see your `PLUGINNAME.json` file inside Calibre's plugin's [config folder](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/master/src/calibre/utils/config.py#L277) (for Windows: `%APPDATA%\calibre\plugins`) (you can get this path programmatically using: `from calibre.utils.config import config_dir` and appending `/plugins`).
2. **Default settings.**

   [`prefs.defaults`](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/master/src/calibre/utils/config.py#L280) is a dictionary which value is [returned](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/master/src/calibre/utils/config.py#L419) if given key doesn't exist in your `prefs` object. So you can create some default values for your plugin's settings, e.g.:

   ```
   prefs.defaults['postimport'] = False
   ```

   The main problem is when you trying to use other dict methods like [`.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), `.items()` or `.iteritems()` they return "real" `prefs`, not defaults, i.e. for our example, if `prefs['postimport']` was not further defined:

   ```
   >>> prefs.defaults['postimport']
   False
   >>> prefs.defaults.items()
   [('postimport', False)]
   >>> prefs['postimport']
   False
   >>> prefs.items()
   []
   ```
3. **Committing nested dict.**

   If you want to use `JSONConfig` object as real `.json` storage you probably want to use nested dictionaries. For example:

   ```
   prefs['pdf'] = {}
   prefs['pdf']['convert'] = True
   ```

   But if you set (or delete) value to nested dictionary `prefs['pdf']` it [will not](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/master/src/calibre/utils/config.py#L429) be saved to `.json` file. You have to:

   ```
   prefs.commit()
   ```

   to save data to file after setting them to nested dict.
4. **Constraints of JSON format.**

   A few of Python features cannot be translated to JSON format, e.g. JSON has not tuples, so [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) [translates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) tuples to arrays. Also in Python you can have an every hashable object (e.g. tuple, or frozenset) as a key. JSON accepts only strings.